# Prove property of floor function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that, for any $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$, $\bigl\lfloor \frac{a}{bc} \bigr\rfloor = \Bigl\lfloor \frac{\bigl\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \bigr\rfloor}{c} \Bigr\rfloor$.

I have no idea how to prove this. Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: It may be useful to note this would also be $$\bigg\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\frac ac\rfloor}{b}\bigg\rfloor$$

Comment: Please read the entirety of the following post: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  Then, please edit your post accordingly, Iulian.

Answer (score 0):

If either $b$ or $c$ divides $a$, this is trivial based off the transposability highlighted in my comment.

Suppose $\frac ab=I+F$, where $I$ is the integer part, $F$ is the fractional part. Thus, $\lfloor I+F\rfloor=I$, and so this problem summarises to proving:
$$\bigg\lfloor\frac{I+F}{c}\bigg\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor\frac{I}{c}\bigg\rfloor$$

For $0\le F<1$

Can you do this?